# Is it possible to know the memory being allocated by the method "CreateSharedMemoryAndSemaphores"?

Tags: database, postgresql, memory-management, shared-memory, postgresql-9.4

I am a newbie to databases and Postgres and I am analyzing the memory being allocated by Postgres in the method "CreateSharedMemoryAndSemaphores".

Like variable "size" starts with a default value of 100000 and then adds a bunch of shared memory like "SpinlockSemaSize", "LockShmemSize" etc.

Is there a way to know which the individual method add how much of memory to the variable?

```
    size = 100000;
    size = add_size(size, SpinlockSemaSize());
    size = add_size(size, hash_estimate_size(SHMEM_INDEX_SIZE,
                                             sizeof(ShmemIndexEnt)));
    size = add_size(size, BufferShmemSize());
    size = add_size(size, LockShmemSize());
    size = add_size(size, PredicateLockShmemSize());
    size = add_size(size, ProcGlobalShmemSize());
    size = add_size(size, XLOGShmemSize());
    size = add_size(size, CLOGShmemSize());
    size = add_size(size, CommitTsShmemSize());
    size = add_size(size, SUBTRANSShmemSize());
    size = add_size(size, TwoPhaseShmemSize());
    size = add_size(size, BackgroundWorkerShmemSize());
    size = add_size(size, MultiXactShmemSize());
    size = add_size(size, LWLockShmemSize());
    size = add_size(size, ProcArrayShmemSize());
    size = add_size(size, BackendStatusShmemSize());
    size = add_size(size, SInvalShmemSize());
    size = add_size(size, PMSignalShmemSize());
    size = add_size(size, ProcSignalShmemSize());
    size = add_size(size, CheckpointerShmemSize());
    size = add_size(size, AutoVacuumShmemSize());
```

Actual code: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/848ef42bb8c7909c9d7baa38178d4a209906e7c1/src/backend/storage/ipc/ipci.c

Answer (score 0):

To figure out the *exact* amount each line contributes to the total, you'd have to read the individual function definitions.

But normally by far the largest part comes from

```
size = add_size(size, BufferShmemSize());
```

where the space for the *shared buffers*, the shared PostgreSQL page cache, is calculated.

In `BufferShmemSize()`, the big contribution is from this line:

```
/* size of data pages */
size = add_size(size, mul_size(NBuffers, BLCKSZ));
```

`NBuffers` is a global variable containing the `postgresql.conf` parameter `shared_buffers` (a [GUC](http://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-plus-edb-blog/bruce-momjian/what-guc-variable) in PostgreSQL parlance), and `BLCKSZ` is 8192 unless manually changed in `pg_config.h`, which virtually nobody does.

Comment: Is it possible to find the value of the shared memory calculation ( the value calculated in the method CreateSharedMemoryAndSemaphores() in ipci.c file) without starting the postgres engine using some sort of utility or any other process?

Comment: Look how big the shared memory segment on the machine is. This will be operating system dependent; on Linux, you would use `ipcs -m`.

Comment: That can be found only after starting postgres db engine. I would like a way to find it without starting postgres db engine.

Comment: As I said, if `shared_buffers` is not a good enough estimate for you, you'll have to go through all the function definitions by hand.